# Can't connect to c++ linux sockets program from outside local network

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, firewall, portforwarding

I have a ubuntu linux server which is running a c++ socket program which should listen on port 6555 for incoming connections and send "Welcome to the server!" to them. It works when I telnet from localhost, but when I telnet from outside the network it doesn't work.

The local network administrator has told me he has forwarded the port 6555 to the server's local IP, as he did previously for 80.

I also have a web server running on the 80 port, and I can telnet into that from anywhere, so I don't know what the problem is.

I tried disabling the iptables (ufw) firewall on my server temporarily and trying to connect, but there was no difference.

Open Port Checker says the port is closed. Does this mean the forwarding has not worked?
Here is the code, compiled in g++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "../include/netutils.hh"

int main() {
    sockaddr_storage clt_addr;
    socklen_t sin_size;
    int cltSock = -1;
    const std::string port = "6555";
    int servSock = -1;
    try {
        servSock = getSrvSocket(port, 10);
        while (true) {
            sin_size = sizeof clt_addr;
            cltSock = accept(servSock, (sockaddr*)&clt_addr, &sin_size);
            if (cltSock == -1) continue;
            if (!fork()) {
                close(servSock);
                send(cltSock, "Welcome to the server!\n", 23, 0);
                while(true);
            }
            close(cltSock);
        }

    }
    catch(std::string excpt)
    {
        std::cerr << excpt << '\n';
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

with getSrvSocket() in netutils.cc:

```
int getSrvSocket(std::string port, int BACKLOG) {
    int yes = 1;
    addrinfo *p;
    addrinfo hints;
    addrinfo *servinfo;
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;     //Can use either IPv4 or IPv6
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;     //Automatically set IP address
    int sock = -1;
    if (getaddrinfo(NULL, port.c_str(), &hints, &servinfo) !=0) {
        throw std::string("Error: Could not resolve address info");
    }

    for (p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        sock = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol);
        if (sock == -1) continue;
        if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes,
                    sizeof(int)) == -1) {
            throw std::string("Error: setsockopt() failure");
        }
        if (bind(sock, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
            close(sock);
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }
    freeaddrinfo(servinfo);
    if (NULL == p) throw std::string("Error: Server failed to bind");
    if (listen(sock, BACKLOG) == -1) {
        throw std::string("Error: Failed to to start listen()");
    }
    struct sigaction sa;
    sa.sa_handler = sigchld_handler;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;

    if (sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, NULL) == -1) {
        throw std::string("Error: sigaction() failed");
    }
    return sock;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`getSrvSocket()` is specifying `AF_UNSPEC` when calling `getaddrinfo()`, which means it can output both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.  But you are only binding to one address and then stopping.  So it is *possible* that you are actually binding to an IPv6 address, and then your client is trying to connect to it using IPv4 instead (or vice versa), which will obviously not work.

If you want to support both IPv4 and IPv6, you should bind a separate listening socket to each address that `getaddrinfo()` returns.  You should also log the addresses that you successfully bind to, so you know what clients can connect to (and what you need to tell the network admin to forward to).

Otherwise, don't use `AF_UNSPEC` with `getaddrinfo()`.  Use `AF_INET` (IPv4) or `AF_INET6` (IPv6) instead.

Comment: I changed it to use AF_INET and tested; it still worked on localhost but still didn't work from external network.

Comment: To expand on this, you can also end up with errors if `IPV6_V6ONLY` defaults to true on your system.

Comment: How can I check if IPV6_V6ONLY is true or false? I think the process is running on IPv4 from running netstat -tulpn and getting tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6555            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10292/netsrv

Comment: @RobNo: If you still cannot connect over the network, then either the client is connecting to the wrong IP/Port, there is no network route between the client and your server (make sure the network router's port forwarding is configured correctly), or a firewall is blocking the connection.

Comment: @RobNo: the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ipv6.7.html) for `IPV6_V6ONLY` says "*The default value for [IPV6_V6ONLY] is defined by the contents of the file `/proc/sys/net/ipv6/bindv6only`. The default value for that file is 0 (false).*" However, you should not rely on that, just set the value explicitly via `setsockopt()` based on your own needs when you create an `AF_INET6` socket. When `IPv6_V6ONLY` is disabled, an `AF_INET6` socket can support both IPv4 and IPv6 peers if the OS supports dual-stack sockets, which simplifies coding, but not all platforms support that.

Comment: @RobNo: if `IPV6_V6ONLY` is enabled, you run into an error if an IPv4 client tries to connect to an IPv6 server, same as if `IPV6_V6ONLY` is not supported at all.

Comment: What firewall could be blocking the connection? The only one I can think of is the iptables on my server, and I turned that off.

Comment: Since you are dealing with someone else as the network admin, maybe he has another firewall setup on the network that you don't know about.  Or maybe the client is behind its own firewall.  You haven't provided any information about your network setup or test environment, so we can't possibly tell you why your client is not reaching your server. Talk to the network admin and have him debug the connection while you run your tests.